# UPS Customer Integration Environment (CIE) Notice?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I just got a notice from UPS that says the following:

> As a valued partner, we want to ensure that as we approach the busiest season of the year, we continue to meet your company needs.
>
> This message is to inform you that you are currently using UPS
> Developer Kit APIs in the Customer Integration Environment (CIE),
> which is not intended to perform as the UPS® production environment.
> To avoid slow response times or planned outages, please migrate to the
> UPS production environment by November 25, 2014.
>
> If you have questions regarding this migration, click here to contact
> UPS Developer Kit Support.

with a link to http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/techsupport/developercenter.html

How will this affect the current UPS shipping module in Magento? And is there any fix to make this compatible with the above request for Magento at the moment?

Comment: In Magento there is a setting for using live or test(sandbox) UPS environment. If you are not using live you should switch to this.  As William W says sounds like just a notice though for you to check.  If you are running test env you will see incorrect rating so worth switching just from that perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the UPS Developer Kit Tech Support (800-247-9035) and they told me this email was sent to anyone who used the Test API endpoint in the past 12 months.

If you are printing real labels currently, then there is nothing to worry about. They just sent out a deceptively alarming email.